# USB hard drive not accessible from Ubuntu VMware guest on Windows 10 host

Tags: ubuntu, usb, virtual-machine, vmware, usb-storage

**Hardware configuration**

1. USB external hard drive (previously internal); here there are three partitions (i) Ubuntu, (ii) Windows 10, (iii) data;
2. internal SSD; here there is Windows 10 and the virtual machine Ubuntu mounted thanks to VMware.

**Problem**

The Ubuntu virtual machine is not able to detect the USB hard drive. My goal is to access to the Ubuntu partition (the one I mentioned in point 1 above) from the Ubuntu virtual machine. See the section figures of the problem below.

**Additional information**

The Windows and data partitions on the external HD can be accessed by the Windows 10 (the host) on the internal SSD.

**Figures of the problem**

Below the out ome of the lsusb command before connecting the old HD.
[image]

Below the out ome of the lsusb command after connecting the old HD.
[image]

---

EDIT: the command lsblk gives the same result both when the HD is connected/disconnected.

[image]

---

EDIT 2 (don't consider the seagate external HD; it's another one)

1. External HD connected to the host (no presence in Disk Manager)
   [image]
2. External HD connected to the guest
   [image]

EDIT 3: I'm using VMware pro 16. The command `dmesg` gives [this output](https://mega.nz/file/NUFimbyC#cxgoXyINWgK43ZZPC2jj47we1GyhewuYuX_myiyCOCQ) when the external HD is disconnected. Instead the output of the command `lspci -k` is [this one](https://mega.nz/file/NRsW2b4C#r68qLovHyp4heTGgZA7cVVufp_Nimuz9BkNm2GBIkhw).

Comment: go on... probe available block devices with `lsblk` before and most importantly, after the above. The external disk should appear, and be `mount`-able.

Comment: Hello @Hannu see the edit please

Comment: Is the disk accessible from Windows? You might need to "hand it over" to the VM. Normally when you re-connect a USB-device you get a dialog asking whether to use it from a VM or from the host. It won't be accessible from the guest OS unless you have done this.

Comment: @Hannu Yes I can access from the host; the dialog box doesn't appear

Comment: Check how the external disk appears in "Device manager" and "Disk manager" (right click "This computer", select "Manage" ...)

Comment: Hi @Hannu I added figures to my question

Comment: Hmm... the text to those images seems odd... Host; the OS where you run VMWare. Guest; The OS that is running in the virtual machine, under VMWare. If I swap those texts, then they make sense: When the disk is connected to the Guest, it should not show up in the Host - and that time it should be available for sensing in the Guest. Which doesn't seem to happen here. As `lsusb` doesn't seem to list it, something is missing or not sensed correctly. Therefore `lsblk` won't see it.

Comment: I don't see a 3.0 root hub being listed under Ubuntu. Have you checked `lspci -k` and `dmesg` to see what's going on with the XHCI controller?

Comment: What version of VMware are you using btw?

Comment: Hello @TomYan sorry for the delay. I edited my question, can you hel me to interpret the output of the commands please?

Comment: In the `Virtual Machine Settings` of the Ubuntu VM, what's your current choice for `USB compatibility` in `USB Controller`? (And how many `USB Controller` have you added?)

Comment: @TomYan thank you very very much for the suggestion, now it works. It was 2.0 and I changed it to 3.1.